# How to replace text of anchor tag without deleting any inner tags?

Tags: jquery

How to replace text of anchor tag without deleting any inner tags?

```
<div class="xyz">
  <a>Hello <b class="caret"></b></a>
</div>

$('.xyz').click(function(){
  $(this).find('a').text('hello2');  
});
```

JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/DXR32/

When the blue area is click i'm changing the text within anchor tag , but even the b tag within anchor also goes off.
Anyway to fix this?

Comment: does the 'Hello' need to be in the anchor too? You said when the blue square is clicked, do you want the function to be triggered on the words too?

Comment: What would you want the resulting html to look like in this situation?

Comment: resulting output should be when blue box is clicked hello changes to 'hello2' with the blue box still there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like the following would work, appending the button onto the end of any text changes: http://jsfiddle.net/DXR32/1/

```
var blueButton = '<b class="caret"></b>';

$('.xyz').click(function(){
   $(this).find('a').html('hello2 '+blueButton); 
});
```

Edit:

Or, as @Nikola Radosavljević and @François Wahl suggest below, encapsulating the text you want changing within its own element inside the anchor like so:

```
<div class="xyz">
    <a><span class="switchable">Hello</span> <b class="caret"></b></a>
</div>

$('.xyz').click(function(){
   $(this).find('.switchable').text('hello2');
});
```

this avoids having to hard code any button html, and also allows you to reuse the click function on any number of anchor elements, all they need is their own `span` with class `switchable` containing the text you want to switch out, for example;

```
<div class="xyz">
    <a><span class="switchable">Click Me 1</span> <b class="caret"></b></a>
</div>
<div class="xyz">
    <a><span class="switchable">Click Me 2</span> <b class="caret2"></b></a>
</div>
<div class="xyz">
    <a><span class="switchable">Click Me 3</span> <b class="caret3"></b></a>
</div>

$('.xyz').click(function(){
   $(this).find('.switchable').text('You Clicked Me!');
});
```

Obviosuly your app may differ completely from that last example.

Comment: What if there is more html elements? I know OP only has that `<b>` tag but if that changes in the future, what if the class now becomes `caret 2` or another class is added? Having to update the `blueButton` variable is not very reliable and open to a lot of risk. Nothing should be hard-coded and though this solution works I do believe adding a span tag for the text as suggested to enable a more generic way without hard-coding any elements or text is better practice.

Comment: @François Wahl, thanks you're absolutely right, edited answer to include this example

Answer (score 2):

You have two options

- [Enclose content you want to change into a tag and change it](http://jsfiddle.net/3BCNp/1/)

> ```
> <div class="xyz">
>     <a><span id="hello">Hello </span><b class="caret"></b></a>
> </div>
> $('.xyz').click(function() {
>     $(this).find('#hello').text('hello2');
> });
> ```

- [Do string replace (which is bad for anything more complex than hello world)](http://jsfiddle.net/m6Evb/1/)

> ```
> $('.xyz').click(function() {
>     var a = $(this).find("a");
>     a.html(a.html().replace("Hello ", "Hello2 "));    
> });
> ```

Comment: +1 for suggesting the `span` tag. that solution is more generic. All the other solution either hard-coded the `caret element` or the `text`, which as you mentioned is bad.

Answer (score 1):

You can try saving the **.children()** of the anchor before replacing the text, like so:

```
$('.xyz').click(function() {
    var cache = $(this).find('a').children();
    $(this).find('a').text('Hello2');
    $(this).find('a').append(cache);
});​
```

And then **.append()** ing them back after.  I've updated [your jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DXR32/8/) with this.

Comment: +1 for an alternative way to hard-coding elements or text. Nice one.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.xyz').click(function(){
   var b = '<b class="caret"></b>'; 
   $(this).find('a').html('hello2' + b);    
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DXR32/3/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.xyz').click(function(){
    $(this).find('a').html(function(i, oldHtml) {
      return oldHtml.replace('Hello', 'hello2');
    });
});    
​
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/DXR32/7/)**